# Sklearn - multiclass text classification

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

I took a challenge to classify bugs (by scanning their logs) into a different groups (classes).
I've already accomplished part of the task by fetching + cleaning the data, but I'm now stuck on getting a very low score of prediction.

I feel like I'm missing the basics and I need some direction.
2 questions I have:

1. should I balance the dataset I'm using before feeding it to the classifier?
   e.g. lets say I've the below mapping of :

{A: 100, B: 20, C: 350, D: 120, E: 220}

**Should I leave it as is?, should I balance so each class type will hold equal amount of bugs?**

I've seen some demonstrations of classifying Spam/Not spam or Cats/Dogs where it was required, but on the other hand I've read here: https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-scikit-learn-12f1e60e0a9f
That I should leave it as is.

2. I've divided the features into ~5 different columns and I'm not sure it's the way to go.
   For instance, I've:

errors, python traces, other traces, test traces, test errors ==> label

**Is it too much? Does having too many features set damage the prediction?**

Now matter what I've done (using balanced/unbalanced dataset) gave me very low score (never passed 40%)

I've been using TFIDF vectoriser and AutoML for testing many classifiers at once.

Comment: Fair question, Is it possible for you to share a sample of your training data?
How was the data labelled? What criteria did you take on this? I suspect this may be the root cause

Comment: @JulioJesusLuna Unfortunately I cannot share the data, but basically what I'm doing is gathering all the info from a bug (i.e. errors, panics, traces, python traces, etc).
For traces, I'm using regex to normalize them (i.e. remove line numbers).
Eventually, all this data becomes a list of strings - this is the features.
For the labelling part, I've came with a system to understand who's the bug owner, and finally use a mapping for owner ==> relevant group.
Later on I'm using TFIDF and numerous classifiers - this is pretty much all